# VS2012 Very Slow in Debug Mode

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Recently I start to have problems with debugging within my VS2012 (with Update 1). The behavior is generally very slow to bring up the page even when the page has very little code. I see the "Build succeeded" message on the bottom but from there it takes forever for the page to show up and the HD seems to be busy spinning. Sometimes I get "Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server did not respond in a timely manner." error. But if I retry a couple of times and finally get the page to show up the next time it will be instantaneous if I don't change anything in the code. Once I modify something on the page this problems shows up again.

I've tried the following but none of them helped:

1. Cache the symbol files locally (Tools | Options - Debugging -> Symbol)
2. Delete all breakpoints

Anyone has any experience with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: usually is related to insufficient RAM. Every new release want more...

Comment: It happened to me also. Five days ago debugger was working well. Now it's almost impossible to work. What I was changed? Deinstaled an extension. Also removed Windowsazure tools. Any ideas?